# How to share with a collaborator only one branch from a private GitHub repo, as a read-only?

Tags: git, github

I am new to collaborating with GitHub.

I have a private repository with different directories.

I want to share one specific directory with a collaborator as a read-only.

I read this: [Share a private git repository on GitHub with a specific user as read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361422/share-a-private-git-repository-on-github-with-a-specific-user-as-read-only)

And this: [What is good way to share one branch of git repo with someone using Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295751/what-is-good-way-to-share-one-branch-of-git-repo-with-someone-using-github)

However, it is still not clear to me.

1) Creating an orphan branch would allow me to keep updating it and committing as I'd do in master?

Ideally, I would be able to keep updating that branch, and collaborator see these changes, but not other parts of the repo.

Creating a new repo with only this directory or sharing the files would of course do the job, but I would like to know and understand if that ideal scenario is possible with github.

Answer (score 7):

### Create a *share repo* with only the one branch

To make sure someone can only see a single branch, you'll have to make a separate repo with only that branch. I'll call it the `share repo` below.

GitHub doesn't have a UI to do this entirely on GitHub, so you have to first create the `share repo` locally, and then push it up to a new corresponding share repo on GitHub.

The local `share repo` will have two `git remote` links: one to fetch the single branch from the main repo on GitHub, and a second to push it to the `share repo` on GitHub.

1. **Create the local `share repo`.**

   Don't use `git clone` as that copies everything. Instead, manually create the directory for the local share repo, `cd` into it, then run `git init`.

   Set up a `git remote` pointing to the main GitHub repo. Choose a helpful name for this remote link so you don't confuse it with the other one you will create in step 2. A good standard name would be `upstream`, but choose whatever helps you most. Do not name it `origin`, which tends to imply a full clone.

   Use `git fetch` to fetch just the single branch (or multiple specific branches if you want to share more than one).
2. **Create the GitHub `share repo`.**

   On GitHub, create the new GitHub `share repo` which you will make available to your collaborator. Name it whatever make sense.

   In your local `share repo`, set up a `git remote` to the new GitHub `share repo`. Again, choose a good name as discussed above.
   Push the the shared branch to this remote.

   Use `git push --force` to push the branch to the GitHub `share repo`. See below for why I recommend using `--force`.

   Make this new repo available to any collaborators.
3. To keep the shared branch in sync with the main repo, use the local `share repo` to fetch commits from the main repo and push them to the GitHub `share repo`.

### Access control

You can use whatever access controls GitHub allows for your type of account and repo, but it really isn't necessary.

The `share repo` is just a copy of the branch from the main `upstream` repo. It's not the source. Just tell them not to write to it.

But even if they do, any changes made to it will not travel upstream (unless you make it). And when you push changes downstream, from main repo to the GitHub `share repo`, you can use `git push -force` to overwrite any changes inadvertently made on the share. The branch will then be guaranteed to be an exact copy of the upstream version.

Let me know if anything isn't clear, and I can augment my answer.

Comment: OK I got stuck already on the first point. An example with code if possible would be very helpful. To be specific as where I got stuck. After creating `share repo` and doing `git init` the `share repo`, a directory called `https:` appears in the current directory. Then I `cd` into `https:` and do `git remote` the `whole original repo` and get the error `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @alejandro I have no idea what you're doing, and it's more than you're saying because there is now way an `http:` appears in the current directory otherwise. You really need to spend some time understanding git. The purpose of this site isn't to do your learning work for you, but to help you when you get stuck.

Comment: @alejandro If you create a new (empty!) dir, `cd` into it, then run `git init`, there will be nothing in that dir except the `.git` dir, which you shouldn't touch. Once you have that, you can proceed to the other steps --  but as I said above, if you don't understand any part of any of the steps in my answer, you need to do some reading on it before proceeding.